# How to use tab to go out of inline math mode (VSCode)?

Tags: visual-studio-code, latex, code-snippets

How can I configure VSCode that when editing latex documents it skips out of the inline math mode when I hit <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd>, i.e. `$some inline math, cursor is here ->$ <- cursor should move here`? When defining snippet one can specify this behaviour quite easily so I assume that this is possible.